# How to add new components dynamically in Angular

Tags: .net, angular

I want to create a nested structure where new replies are shown under the previous reply dynamically on click of a button.

I have created a recursive component where the replies are passed to the aforementioned component where a nested structure is formed. Now i want the nested replies to be generated when show replies is clicked on individual replies